# Batch File Find Path of Exe and Run Program

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a batch file that finds the browser on a machine and runs a url. I was able to find the code to find a exe and I know how to run a url when the Browser path is hard coded, but I cant seem to put both of those together

```
 //Comment - Finds the browser Path of firefox
 @echo off set BrowserPath = dir /s /b firefox.exe
 //Comment - uses that browser path found to run url 
 "%BrowserPath%" "http://www.cnn.com"
```

Also does anyone know of a command that works faster than dir /s /b firefox.exe

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `wmic product where name="Firefox" get InstallLocation` can help (I don't have it installed; Maybe the name differs; try `wmic product get Name, InstallLocation |find /i "Firefox"` to find out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an old question but there's no real answer to this and somebody else seems to be looking for it.

Use `for` to execute a command and store a result to a variable

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=/" %%i IN (`dir /s /b firefox.exe`) DO set BrowserPath=%%i
"%BrowserPath%" "http://www.cnn.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to search for the exe. The `start` command will do that for you:

```
start http://www.cnn.com
```

will open the URL with the default browser (note: **no** quotes around the URL)

Comment: I have to run a specific browser, when they might have multiple browsers which is firefox

Comment: @AC25: so what do you do if Firefox is not installed?

Comment: going to write an if statement and run ie,

Comment: @AC25: I for one would be annoyed if you opened that URL in a browser that I didn't choose to be my default. But that's just me. If you have the requirement to always open it in Firefox regardless of the user's preferences then this indeed is no solution.

Comment: @AC25: So why not just run the browser *the user chose as default*. I get really irritated when an app starts IE when my preferred choice is something else.

Comment: its a requirement, i am just trying to find out how to use the path once recieved and run the browser, I already can run c:\whereever\firefox.exe http:\\www.cnn.com, just trying to write the batch that put it together

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done it is almost correct - just put `start` before `"%BrowserPath%"`.

```
set BrowserPath = dir /s /b firefox.exe
start "%BrowserPath%" www.cnn.com
```

I have yet to come across a quicker way of searching for a file in Batch.

Comment: `set`will not set the variable to the path to the browser, but simply to the string ` dir /s /b firefox.exe" Also `start "I am an ugly string" www.cnn.com` works. The first parameter in quotes simply supplies a title to the new window (which you won't see, as a browser-windows does not accept a title).